# Detectar a URL de onde o iframe está sendo exibido

Tags: javascript, html

Como detectar a URL onde o `iframe` está sendo exibido e executar uma função se a pagina estiver sendo exibida em uma URL específica.

**Exemplo:** ao acessar a página `https://www.../exemplo.html` ***(não necessariamente do mesmo domínio)*** um `iframe` com o `src='//www.../iframe.html'` será exibido, em seguida um script dentro do `iframe` vai detectar se o iframe está sendo exibido na **URL** `//www.../exemplo.html`. Se sim, vai executar um comando, se não, vai executar outro comando.

- Página de exemplo: [https://editor.sollic.com/stackoverflow/exemplo](https://editor.sollic.com/stackoverflow/exemplo.html)
- Src do iframe: https://editor.sollic.com/stackoverflow/iframe
- Script de exemplo para identificar se a página está sendo exibida em um iframe:

```js
  window.onload = function iframe(){
    var frame = window.frameElement;
    var origem = //identificar onde o iframe está sendo exibido
    if(frame){
      if(origem != "https://editor.sollic.com/stackoverflow/exemplo.html"){
        //código aqui
      }else{
        //código aqui
      }
    }
  }
```

**Iframe de exemplo:**

```html
<iframe src="//editor.sollic.com/stackoverflow/iframe"></iframe>
```

Comment: Sua pergunta está um pouco vaga. Não consegui muito bem o que você deseja fazer... Poderia tentar clarificar um pouco mais por favor?

Comment: @LuizFelipe alterei a pergunta

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/935127/how-to-access-parent-iframe-from-javascript

Comment: pelo que entendi vc quer saber se uma pagina sua está sendo usada como iframe em outra página qualquer, e qual é a url dessa página externa é isso?

Comment: isso mesmo, se eu usar `parent` ele retorna a url, mas se caso o iframe estiver dentro de outro iframe, ele vai retornar a url do iframe pai e não a da pagina.

Comment: Tente document.referrer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use:

```
top.window.document.location.href
```

Irá retornar a URL do documento mais *alto*, independentemente de qual `iframe` você chamar.

Por exemplo:

```
http://site.com/index.html
     |
     ----> iframe1.html (retorna http://site.com/index.html)
                |
                ----> iframe2.html (retorna http://site.com/index.html)
                           |
                           ----> iframe3.html (retorna http://site.com/index.html)
```